# Is there a better way to replicate this CSS code

Tags: javascript, css, list, github, github-pages

I'm looking for a better way to replicate this without having to use \A after every line break. It's going to be used on github-pages so I can't, to my knowledge, use server side language.

I want to have a separate file so I can withdraw lists from it and put them on different pages.

```css
     .list1:before {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
       content: "list1 text \A list1 text \A list1 text" ;
      }
    
     .list2:before {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
       content: "list2 text \A list2 text \A list2 text" ;
      } 

     .list3:before {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
       content: "list3 text \A list3 text \A list3 text" ;}
```

```html
 <ul class=list1></ul>

 <ul class=list2></ul>

 <ul class=list3></ul>
```

Comment: Why not use `li` tags?

Comment: It's rendered as one list item because of the coding. Bullets or numbers will only appear on the first list item.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use nth-child like:

```css
.content div::before {
   display: block;
   white-space: pre;
}
.content div:nth-child(1)::before {
    content: "list1 text \A list1 text \A list1 text" ;
}
.content div:nth-child(2)::before {
    content: "list2 text \A list2 text \A list2 text" ;
}
.content div:nth-child(3)::before {
    content: "list3 text \A list3 text \A list3 text" ;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you specify which list appears doing it that way? The same list will appear on several pages in no particular order.

Answer (score 0):

Storing your content in css is not really standard practice. Using `:before` and `content` are usually reserved for inserting visible items that contribute to the style of the page ( icons and graphics ) rather than content.

I think you have two options here

1. keep your content in the html and show/hide it with js.
2. dynamically insert your content with js.

I've provided an example of choice 2. There is probably a better way to js this.  This is pretty quick and dirty.  :-)

Also [here is a link](http://codepen.io/aljachimiak/pen/VLLZoy) that you can play around with.

```js
var list1 = "<li>apples</li> <li>oranges</li> <li>pears</li>";

var list2 = "<li>cars</li> <li>trucks</li> <li>trains</li>";

var list3 = "<li>carrots</li> <li>corn</li> <li>onions</li>";

function InsertListContents(listNum) {
  var contents = "";
  switch (listNum) {
    case 1:
      contents = list1;
      break;
    case 2:
      contents = list2;
      break;
    case 3:
      contents = list3;
      break;
    default:
      contents = "<li>sorry, no content found</li>";
  }

  $('.list' + listNum).html(contents);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // make a decision on which list to show
  // This is random, you'll want write your own function to decide
  var listNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;

  InsertListContents(listNum);

  // for demonstration purposes
  $('.list' + listNum).addClass("example");
})
```

```css
.example {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button onclick='InsertListContents(1)'>1</button>
  <button onclick='InsertListContents(2)'>2</button>
  <button onclick='InsertListContents(3)'>3</button>
  <ul class='list1'></ul>

  <ul class='list2'></ul>

  <ul class='list3'></ul>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p class='example'>*blue content was inserted at random</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Choice 2 is close to what I'm looking for. It can't be random.

Comment: Right - you'll have to write some javascript that chooses the correct content to display.  You need to replace that line with code that makes the decision that is right for your page and content.

Comment: If you're using gh-pages, figuring out Jekyll and how to use partials and layouts is probably the most correct solution.